# Gatsby template for articles protected by firebase auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, gatsby

I have been trying to build a little site using GatsbyJS with protected content using Firebase, following this example:https://github.com/taming-the-state-in-react/gatsby-firebase-authentication. I am using DatoCMS as a source. I have built blogs before where everything was the same except for the firebase authentication part, and everything worked perfectly fine.

Somehow, I get the error of data not being defined inside my template file out of which the article-pages are generated.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import AuthUserContext from '../components/Session/AuthUserContext';
import withAuthorization from '../components/Session/withAuthorization';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';


const authCondition = authUser => !!authUser;

const WikiPageSingle = withAuthorization(authCondition)(() => (
    <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
      {authUser => (
        <div>
          <h1>{this.props.data.datoCmsArticle.id}</h1>
        </div>
      )}
    </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
))



export default withAuthorization(authCondition)(WikiPageSingle);

    export const query = graphql`
    query ArticlQuery ($slug: String!) {
    datoCmsArticle (slug: { eq: $slug }) {
          id
          title
          slug
          }
        }
  `;
```

I know it might be hard to get help on this since its kind of a very specific issue but any ideas or pointers why this wouldn't work on a template file would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by creating a new layout for those articles and basically protecting the whole content inside that layout. I still feel there must be a more elegant solution so any ideas are more than welcome. In the meantime, here is how I got it working in case someone else has this issue in the future:

New Layout component:

```
import React from 'react';

import AuthUserContext from '../components/Session/AuthUserContext';
import withAuthorization from '../components/Session/withAuthorization';
import withAuthentication from './Session/withAuthentication';


const authCondition = authUser => !!authUser;

const ArticleLayout = withAuthorization(authCondition)(({children}) => (
  <AuthUserContext.Consumer>
    {authUser => (
      <div>
         {children}
      </div>
    )}
  </AuthUserContext.Consumer>
));

export default withAuthentication(ArticleLayout);
```

And here my template in the templates folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import { graphql } from 'gatsby';
import ArticleLayout from '../components/articlelayout';

class BlogPost extends React.Component {
  render() {

    return (
      <ArticleLayout>
      <div>
          <h1>{this.props.data.datoCmsArticle.title}</h1>
      </div>
      </ArticleLayout>
    )
  }
}

export default BlogPost


export const query = graphql`
  query PostQuery ($slug: String!) {
  datoCmsArticle (slug: { eq: $slug }) {
        id
        title
        slug
        }
      }
`;
```